# Loop in Javascript using Django variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I get my table from database in Django views :

```
events = EventHistory.objects.all().order_by('-DT_NoAck')
```

I can access my table in my templates (Html) using the tag :

```
{% for event in events %} myvar : {{event.Message}} {% endfor%}
```

This works. What I want to do now is doing this in Javascript.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    ...
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];
  for (event in {{events}}) {
      availableTags.push(event.Message)
      }
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags});
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. There are syntax error and/or my variable is not recognised in Javascript.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is a quick solution where you essentially use the django for loop to create a static array in javascript but this isn't a great solution. You'd be better to make a separate ajax request to retrieve a `JsonResponse`

Comment: I dont know anythings about ajax or Json. Do you have an easy example?

Comment: More over I can't read array from Django it would give the same problem until I have found the good syntax.

Comment: I finnaly got the answer. It is possible to use the same tag than in HTML {% for event in events %} Is it a good way? (it works)

Comment: Thats the quick solution I was talking about, which is a viable solution, but there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't know anything about the structure of an Event. Instead of sending a Django model instance to the template and expecting JS to know how to deal with it, send a JSON array of the values you actually want:

```
messages = EventHistory.objects.order_by('-DT_NoAck').values_list('Message', flat=True)
messages = json.dumps(list(messages))
```

JS:

```
availableTags.concat({{ messages|safe }})
```

Comment: this give me an error in Django (for the first line) and I am not using json and I dont know how it works.

Comment: Would have been more helpful to tell me what the error was. Still, there was an extra parenthesis, which I've removed.

Comment: the error is gone thx. but what should i do with the javascript? its not working for me. I can't see the message in the autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :
in javascript :

```
{% for event in events %}
    availableTags.push("{{event.Message}}")
{% endfor %}
```

it works.
PS : i did not found any documentation